# Subquery not outputting the correct result?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I hope someone can help me with this problem, I been trying different combinations but can't seems to get the correct result.

First of all, I have 3 tables, category, department, and master, master has the FK. I want to get sum of total time for each department and sum of total time for category group by department so that I can see which department has how much time for that category, all should be group by department and in the correct order?

I can get the result but not coming out right, here is my code...

```
SELECT a.department, time_spent , COUNT(DISTINCT (a.department)), sum_quarantine FROM 

    (SELECT d.department, SUM(time_spent) as time_spent
    FROM master as m 
    INNER JOIN department as d ON d.dept_id = m.dept_id GROUP BY d.department) AS a,

    (SELECT d.department, c.category, SUM(time_spent) as sum_quarantine
    FROM master as m
    INNER JOIN category as c ON c.cat_id = m.cat_id
    INNER JOIN department as d ON d.dept_id = m.dept_id
    WHERE category = 'Quarantine' GROUP BY d.department) as b

    GROUP BY b.department
```

Comment: Can you show us the output you're getting, and the output you're expecting? Possibly some input data as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be done without sub-query, making use of a `CASE WHEN` in a `SUM`, so that it only sums what you are interested in ('Quarantine'):

```
SELECT     d.department, 
           SUM(CASE c.category
                 WHEN 'Quarantine' THEN time_spent
               END) as sum_quarantine,
           SUM(time_spent) time_spent,
           COUNT(DISTINCT (c.category)) category_count
FROM       master as m
INNER JOIN category as c ON c.cat_id = m.cat_id
INNER JOIN department as d ON d.dept_id = m.dept_id
GROUP BY   d.department
ORDER BY   1
```

Here is [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2944fe/1).

Note that I added a count as well, since there was one in your attempt. But yours would always return 1, so I am not sure what you were looking for. I have added the number of categories linked to the department.

Also you did not specify the order you want, but it is easy to adapt the `ORDER BY` clause. The above query orders results by department, but if for instance you want to order by the second column in descending order, then do:

```
...
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

If your results includes *NULL* values, and you prefer to have zeroes instead, then make use of the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function. For example:

```
COALESCE(SUM(time_spent), 0) time_spent,
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks a bunch. Only problem I have now is with the query return null if a department dont have any values? How do I turn null into 0?

Comment: A search for "MySQL turn null into 0" gives many matches. Use `COALESCE(...., 0)`, where in place of the dots you put whatever could be NULL and should be 0.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is working now. You are a great guy!